# Точки остановки idea 9

Tags: gwt, ide, java, intellij-idea

Пишу обычное приложение на GWT, использую при этом Intellij Idea 9. После открытия проекта не могу поставить точку остановки. Это происходит не всегда, и все время в разных классах. Как это починить?

Comment: При использовании IDEA 10 воспроизводится? В любом случае убедитесь, что пользуетесь Ultimate версией, взятой отсюда: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html

Comment: В Intellij IDEA 10 работа с gwt еще хуже - при запуске web-клиента постоянно появляется сообщение вроде "Приложение приостановлено, отключить плагин?"

Answer (score 1):

Иногда такое бывает. Иногда в hosted mode случается, что не весь код сгенерирован.. в таком случае, прежде чем он будет сгенерирован, нельзя ставить точку.

Обычно полный стоп и пересборка с очисткой помогает. Подобные галлюцинации случаются, когда со временем накапливаются изменения.

Comment: А не могли бы подсказать, как такое лечить? Делать очистку, перестроение проекта или что-то иное?

Comment: Обычно полный стоп и пересборка с очисткой помогает. Подобные галлюцинации случаются, когда со временем накапливаются изменения.

Comment: Нет, такое не помогает.  Причем, после очистки и пере сборки не поставить в другом месте.